# How to Identify the gps is turned off phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, gps

I want to figure out  the  gps is turned on in android device using phonegap.

I tried like

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function onSuccess(position){
            console.log("The gps is availabile");
        },
        function geolocationError(error){
            console.log("The geo error : " + error.code +"code : " + PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED);
           if( error.code == PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED ){
               alert("Please turn on your gps to start the trip");
           }else{
              console.log("Gps is turned on. but not availabile");
           }
        },{enableHighAccuracy: true , timeout:10000 });
```

But when gps is turned off i never gets the `PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED` error. Always it shows the `PositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE` . How i can identify the gps is turned on /off ?.(not the gps availabile or not)

Comment: @Mirko  You can use the android diagnostic plugin. check: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Diagnostic

Comment: but that plugin does not give me back if the Gps is on or off, just if my location settings are on or off, no? If the Gps is off, will my app  switch it on by itself? I do not think so.

Comment: Ah sorry, there is a `isGpsEnabled` flag that might do ;). Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Mirko  Glad to know your problem solved.. :)

Comment: It says the repo is not available, any idea how to use it now?